# Utility to create "data dictionary" for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, data-dictionary

I'm wondering if there is a utility that exists to create a data dictionary for a MySQL database.

I'm considering just writing a php script that fetches the meta data about the database and displays it in a logical format for users to understand but I'd rather avoid that if there is some pre-built utility out there that can simply do this for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean to document your database?

Comment: In my understanding a data dictionary lists all the tables and columns with their data types, limits, default values etc, so yeah, documentation.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the gist of it. We want a utility that would show/explain our database schema/structure to someone unfamiliar with it as best as possible. If you have any ideas that would be great.

Comment: I believe MySQL Workbench will map an existing db. http://wb.mysql.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) or [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/try.php)?

Also, [MySQL Admin](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).

*Edit#1* fixed typo, added more info

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703098/4208132

There is a db_doc.lua plugin for MySQL Workbench CE

[EDITED]

It seems that the LUA plugin support was discontinued.
So I wrote a plugin in Python to generate data dictionaries. 
It is available at: https://github.com/rsn86/MWB-DBDocPy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MySQL Admin is now MySQL Workbench and you need the Enterprise version to get their reporting tool called DBDoc. It explains a little about customizing DBDoc reporting templates at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/dbdoc-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is Download Toad for MySQL, which is free, and create your own query against the mysql information_schema internal database.  You can add columns you want to the query below.  Then select all results and export as csv using TOAD.

use information_schema;

desc columns;

select c.table_name, c.column_name, c.data_type from columns c
where c.table_schema = "mydatabaseinstance";

Comment: Is this still available as a free version? Do you have a link?