# Export Data Dictionary of my database using MySQL Workbench CE?

Tags: mysql, export, mysql-workbench, data-dictionary

I have a database on server with around 60 tables and now I want to export `Data Dictionary` of the database (including table structures)..

I can do that on my local machine which has `PHPMyAdmin`, however, I am not able to find way to export it on server using `Workbench`.

Any one who can help?

Comment: Check this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html

Comment: I know data export - but I am after `Data Dictionary`, that is structure only of all tables including fields, fields type etc

Comment: select Skip table data (no-data)

Comment: Do you really know what Data Dictionary is? I am not after queries to create table.. I am after a list of tables that will show field names, field types and all other structure of tables

Comment: are you looking this for er-diagram?

Answer (score 4):

You may install db_doc.lua, a Lua script plugin for MySQL Workbench that generates data dictionaries, similar to those generated by DBDoc on MySQL Workbench Enterprise.

Download it from:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxXM2ftdUPGeNkM4OGpiYmFxdFk/edit?pli=1

Plugin developer's website
http://tmsanchezdev.blogspot.mx/2013/11/reporte-actualizado-del-modelo-de-la.html

[EDITED]

It seems that the LUA plugin support was discontinued.
So I wrote a plugin in Python to generate data dictionaries. 
It is available at: https://github.com/rsn86/MWB-DBDocPy

Comment: Thanks for writing the script